# Firebase javascript Admin SDK: length of the loaded array is incorrect

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-admin

I have following data in my firebase realtime database.

[image]

I load this data from javascript admin SDK (nodejs).

```
firebaseAdmin.database().ref('db/path').on('value', snapshot => {
    let data = snapshot.val();
});
```

Above data is loaded as an array and the length of the array is incorrect. Following is a visualization of the loaded data.

[image]

It can be seen that array length is shown as 5, even though there are only 4 items in the DB. The element in the zero'th index of the array is null.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: though 0'th index value is `null` but it holds the memory so, array size is 0-4 (length: 5)

Answer (score 0):

The length of a JavaScript array is always 1 + the max index in the array.  In your case, it's 1 + 4 = 5.  Empty elements count toward the size.  This is true for a vast majority of programming languages out there.

Consider starting the array index in your database at 0 if you want to avoid confusion.  A vast majority of programming languages also assume arrays are zero-indexed like this.

Comment: The issue I am facing is, there are only four elements in the `expenses` node, but there are 5 elements in the array returned by admin SDK. (I added only four child nodes to `expenses` node, with property names `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and I expect admin SDK to return an object with properties `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` when I query on `expenses` node, instead of returning an array)

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  And I also explained how JavaScript arrays work.  If you need your array to contain 4 elements instead of 5, you will have to write some additional code to build a new array using the contents of the original array.

Comment: Does firebase treat numeric keys differently? if I use `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` instead of `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`, admin SDK returns an object. But, If I use numbers, it returns an array. (I don't need an inconsistency when iterating nodes, but with this, I have to tread nodes with numeric keys differently. I didn't want my `expenses` node to contain an array. I wanted it to be an object)

Comment: If the keys of an object look like numbers, the result will be an array.  If there are not numbers for the keys, you will get an object.  You might want to read about best practices with lists of data in Realtime Database, as it's not really the best idea to store numeric indexes anyway. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html